# Internet Explorer: jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a simple function that works in chrome, but in Internet explorer (9) it crashes:

```
function go() {
    var selector = "span";
    console.log($);
    answer = $(selector); // errors on this line.
    return answer;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
LOG: function(a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} 
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

So it appears that jQuery is there, and if i run `$("span")` on the IE console it works. So i'm baffled. Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: Turns out it was the word "answer", i must have used it in another context. Simply putting `var` in front of answer solved the problem. But don't forget to remove the console log statements (or use the solution below.

Comment: Be sure you understand what the `var` keyword really does.  Without it, you're essentially declaring the variable as a global variable.  Most of the time, there's no reason to make a variable global (emphasis on **most** of the time).

Comment: Yes, this would not have been a problem if i had paid attention to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE offers a `console.log` function only when the debugger is open. Remove the`console.log($);` and it should work.

Or you could patch it like this :

```
if (!window.console) {
    (function() {
      var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml",
      "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];
      window.console = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
      }
    }());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic console workaround. It's not my problem in this case (I had the console window open while testing this), but very useful solution.

Comment: I'm not the author of this function. Or maybe not the complete author, can't remember.